# How to check for node version in control statements within recipes

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra

In my recipe I would like the control statement to skip auditing phase if the recipe is being run on CentOS 6 version.

I tried using the below for the control statement in RSpec but doesn't seem to work.

How can i use node attributes in control statements to make sure this audit does not run on CentOS 6.x versions and runs on rest of them?

I'm trying to use a recipe and have a control statement at the end like this:

```
control_group "gcloud test" do
  control "gcloud" do
   describe command("/usr/bin/gcloud --version") do
    its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
    not_if { node[:platform_family][:platform_version].to_i == '6' }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to put whole control inside `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The in-recipe audit feature is deprecated and you should switch over to the `audit` cookbook instead.

2) Wrap the whole thing with `if node[:platform_family][:platform_version].to_i != '6' ... end` or similar.